# firebase addValueEventListener leads to duplicated data after update or insert

Tags: android, firebase

I'm getting the created group from fire-base and its OK but when some one else creates a new group in the same tree data is duplicated multiple times and populated to ui using recyclerview.

I have tried overriding the onChildAdded method to get updated List of values but nothing works i also have tried clearing the hole list before the fire-base call..

return duplicated value multiple times

```
final DatabaseReference group_refrence = root_refrence.child("Chatts").child("Groups");
        group_refrence.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    set.add(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getKey());
                }

                list_of_Group.addAll(set);
                if (list_of_Group.isEmpty()) {
                    no_goroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.e("group soze", String.valueOf(list_of_Group.size()));
                }
                setAdapter(list_of_Group);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                no_goroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where did clear the list? Add `list_of_Group.clear()` just before `list_of_Group.addAll(set);`

Comment: I did it but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you add multiple listeners, For example if you add listener in your Activity's `OnCreate` method. And you opened and close activity multiple times, `ValuesEventListener` will be added multiple times. If this is the case, Then in your Activity's `onStop` method you need to  remove listener in this way

```
group_refrence.removeEventListener(your_listener);
```

Comment: Can you sir send some code for calling a firebase by defining the value event listener